# C#. reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Помогите пожалуйста. Можно ли в reportviewer после печати отчета с некоторыми скрытыми полями, сделать экспорт всех полей и скрытых тоже?
Смысл в чем. есть отчет он печатается на форму. Имеются три поля которые печататься не должны. А вот экспортировать их нужно. В свойствах отчета установил значение "hidden-true". На отчет они не вывелись. А вот в экспорт хочу чтобы попали.

Comment: А что такое reportviewer, простите?

Comment: Это компонент .net в котором хранится отчет.

Comment: Никогда не слышал о таком. Это WinForms или WPF?